# Use BIGINT column for java.util.Date or java.time.Instant in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to access an existing MySQL database which uses `BIGINT` columns to store timestamps:

```sql
create table mytable (created bigint);
```

Now I prefer to work with `java.util.Date` or `java.time.Instant` instances instead of integers, so I'm trying to let Hibernate convert the values directly. Unfortunately Hibernate won't recognize the column when annotated like this:

```java
@Column(name = "created")
private Date created;
```

or like this:

```java
@Column(name = "created")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar created;
```

This does return something in the future like `2017-07-01T04:14:00+02:00`. How can I make Hibernate convert `BIGINT` columns properly so I don't have to convert them in getters and setters?

Comment: Does it work with the timestamp when stored as such? (the second example) such that you don't have to manipulate the data any more before using it, and what is written is what is read in?

Comment: I figured out that the stored timestamps are seconds since the epoch, and not milliseconds as expected from hibernate. I created a UnixTimestampType that transforms the values from seconds to milliseconds and vice versa.

Comment: Then congrats and a little bump for your exploratory efforts :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate's `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP` maps to `java.sql.Timestamp`. The `Timestamp` constructor takes Long values which is the number of milliseconds since the epoch. The values in database are stored as Unix timestamps which is the number of seconds since the epoch.

I wrote a `UnixTimestampType` that takes seconds instead of milliseconds and creates `Date` instances:

```
public class UnixTimestampType extends AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<Date> implements IdentifierType<Date>, LiteralType<Date> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final UnixTimestampType INSTANCE = new UnixTimestampType();

    public UnixTimestampType() {
        super(UnixTimestampTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE, JdbcDateTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "date";
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getRegistrationKeys() {
        return new String[] { getName(), java.sql.Date.class.getName() };
    }

    @Override
    public String objectToSQLString(Date value, Dialect dialect) throws Exception {
        final java.sql.Date jdbcDate = java.sql.Date.class.isInstance(value) ? (java.sql.Date) value : new java.sql.Date(value.getTime());
        return StringType.INSTANCE.objectToSQLString(jdbcDate.toString(), dialect);
    }

    @Override
    public Date stringToObject(String xml) {
        return fromString(xml);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class UnixTimestampTypeDescriptor implements SqlTypeDescriptor {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final UnixTimestampTypeDescriptor INSTANCE = new UnixTimestampTypeDescriptor();

    @Override
    public int getSqlType() {
        return Types.INTEGER;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canBeRemapped() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public <X> ValueBinder<X> getBinder(final JavaTypeDescriptor<X> javaTypeDescriptor) {
        return new BasicBinder<X>(javaTypeDescriptor, this) {
            @Override
            protected void doBind(PreparedStatement st, X value, int index, WrapperOptions options) throws SQLException {
                Date date = javaTypeDescriptor.unwrap(value, Date.class, options);
                date.setTime(date.getTime() / 1000);
                st.setDate(index, date);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public <X> ValueExtractor<X> getExtractor(final JavaTypeDescriptor<X> javaTypeDescriptor) {
        return new BasicExtractor<X>(javaTypeDescriptor, this) {
            @Override
            protected X doExtract(ResultSet rs, String name, WrapperOptions options) throws SQLException {
                Date date = new Date(rs.getLong(name) * 1000);
                return javaTypeDescriptor.wrap(date, options);
            }
        };
    }
}
```